# Having too many ADPM and ICMP log in router admin panel

Tags: networking, router, internet, packet, denial-of-service

Recently, I feel that the speed of network became too slow. And I open router admin panel and have a look at the log messages. I found that there are many messages contains word "ADPM" and "ICMP", I don't think it is normal.

Here are the messages:

```
2017/5/12 12:44:54 DPM ep 55270
2017/5/12 12:44:54 ADPM ep 55270 ipa 173 ip 55270 UNo2
2017/5/12 12:45:39 DPM ep 55270
2017/5/12 12:45:39 ADPM ep 55270 ipa 173 ip 55270 UNo2
2017/5/12 12:46:15 DPM ep 55270
2017/5/12 12:46:15 ADPM ep 55270 ipa 173 ip 55270 UNo2
2017/5/12 12:47:00 DPM ep 55270
2017/5/12 12:47:00 ADPM ep 55270 ipa 173 ip 55270 UNo2
2017/5/12 12:47:01 DPM ep 55270
2017/5/12 12:47:02 ADPM ep 55270 ipa 173 ip 55270 UNo2
2017/5/12 12:47:40 DPM ep 55270
2017/5/12 12:47:40 ADPM ep 55270 ipa 173 ip 55270 UNo2
2017/5/12 12:48:11 DPM ep 55270
2017/5/12 12:48:12 ADPM ep 55270 ipa 173 ip 55270 UNo2
2017/5/12 12:48:56 DPM ep 55270
2017/5/12 12:48:56 ADPM ep 55270 ipa 173 ip 55270 UNo2
2017/5/12 12:49:32 DPM ep 55270
2017/5/12 12:49:33 ADPM ep 55270 ipa 173 ip 55270 UNo2
2017/5/12 12:50:10 DPM ep 55270
2017/5/12 12:50:10 ADPM ep 55270 ipa 173 ip 55270 UNo2
2017/5/12 12:50:54 DPM ep 55270
2017/5/12 12:50:54 ADPM ep 55270 ipa 173 ip 55270 UNo2
2017/5/12 12:51:28 DPM ep 55270
2017/5/12 13:19:23 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 218.79.8.132
2017/5/12 13:19:26 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 116.230.34.201
2017/5/12 13:19:26 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 116.230.34.201
2017/5/12 13:19:32 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 218.79.8.132
2017/5/12 13:23:10 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 114.158.250.21
2017/5/12 13:23:10 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 114.158.250.21
2017/5/12 13:23:19 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 114.158.250.21
2017/5/12 13:23:56 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 116.230.34.201
2017/5/12 13:24:00 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 116.230.34.201
2017/5/12 13:24:00 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 116.230.34.201
2017/5/12 13:24:06 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 116.230.34.201
2017/5/12 13:24:10 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 123.203.74.171
2017/5/12 13:24:12 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 218.79.8.132
2017/5/12 13:24:12 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 218.79.8.132
2017/5/12 13:24:12 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 218.79.8.132
2017/5/12 13:24:15 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 218.79.8.132
2017/5/12 13:24:21 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 218.79.8.132
2017/5/12 13:24:21 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 218.79.8.132
2017/5/12 13:24:23 ICMP: type 3 code 13 from 194.135.128.75
2017/5/12 13:26:44 ICMP: type 8 code 0 from 123.233.247.196
2017/5/12 13:26:44 ICMP: type 8 code 0 from 60.216.174.226
2017/5/12 13:26:44 ICMP: type 8 code 0 from 123.233.247.206
2017/5/12 13:26:44 ICMP: type 8 code 0 from 123.232.105.213
2017/5/12 13:26:44 ICMP: type 8 code 0 from 123.232.105.219
2017/5/12 13:26:44 ICMP: type 8 code 0 from 123.233.246.91
2017/5/12 13:27:07 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 94.180.23.101
2017/5/12 13:28:31 ICMP: type 3 code 1 from 23.17.18.187
```

What are these messages mean? And what can I do to make the network become normal?

Comment: Are these inbound from the internet side? Have you disabled any torrents, etc?

Comment: yes, they are from internet side, and these logs are still printed out even I disabled torrents.